# Custom activity failed due to permission

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I have created Azure Batch pool and tasks are running fine using Python with Pool autouser, admin. But when I run same commands from Custom Activity in Data Factory like import pandas or import pyspark it gives me permission error. Azure Batch task is showing up User Identity as nonadmin (pool).

How would I change the user identity to pool or task autouser admin?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

> How would I change the user identity to pool or task autouser admin?

Based on the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-user-accounts#elevated-access-for-tasks),there are two options for elevation level:

- NonAdmin: The task runs as a standard user without elevated access.
  The default elevation level for a Batch user account is always
  NonAdmin.
- Admin: The task runs as a user with elevated access and operates with
  full Administrator permissions.

However, you can't change the permission level of the auto-user account when you using custom activity in ADF.Please see the statement [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity-permissions).